# Como temporizar um anuncio Intersticial?

Tags: java, android, timer, admob, anúncio

Como temporizar um anuncio Intersticial?

Exemplo:  Quero que ao abrir o aplicativo, o anuncio seja exibido em até 5 segundos, caso não seja, a exibição será cancelada e o aplicativo prossiga para a Activity principal.

```js
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Main.this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMobInter));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.adMob_test))
            .build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            
               displayInterstitial();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            
            onMain();


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            
            onMain();

        }
    });

}

public void displayInterstitial() {
  
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded())  {
        interstitialAd.show();

    }
}

public void onMain() {

    setContentView(R.layout.main); }
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem de programação? [tag:java] ou [tag:c#] por exemplo. _Edite na tag se houver_.

Comment: Java ( android studio)

Comment: Francis, não precisa informar a linguagem no titulo, para isso tem as tags embaixo.

Comment: Obrigado @diegofm

Answer (score 1):

Fala Francis,

Tenta fazer dessa forma então:

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    public void onAdLoaded() {
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 

           @Override
           public void onReceiveAd() {
             //Abriu, ta beleza
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailedToReceiveAd(){
            //Dificuldades para abrir
            startActivity();
           }

           @Override
           public void onAdClosed(){
              Log.d("AD Closed", "Ad closed");
              startActivity();
           }

        } 
    }, 5000);
}
```

});

Vão se passar 5 segundos de delay, se cair dentro do onReceiveAd() é porque abriu normalmente, e após ser exibido e fechado vai cair no onAdClosed(), ai é só mandar o usuário pra tela inicial do app.

Caso se passe os 5 segundos e não carregou o anúncio ainda, o usuário vai cair dentro do onFailedToReceiveAd(), ai é só mandar ele pra tela inicial do app, da mesma forma que o onAdClosed().

Abraços.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, agradeço pela dica, mas meu problema é que , quando o usuário do aplicativo esta com a internet fraca, o anuncio fica tentando carregar infinitamente, impedindo o aplicativo de iniciar. Preciso impor uma condição do tipo? SE o anuncio for exibido em 5 segundo(tudo certo), SENAO (cancela anuncio e abre aplicativo)

Comment: Fala Francis, eu alterei a minha resposta, tenta fazer dessa forma agora. Abraços.

Comment: tentei implementar mas não deu certo, consegui postar o meu código na pergunta, dê uma olhada pra vê se dá uma luz !

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
 private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Long exibirAte;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Adicionamos 5 segundos no tempo atual
        Long exibirAte = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+5000;
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();

    }


    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        final InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // se a data atual é maior, então já se passaram 5 segundos...
                if(SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() > exibirAte){
                    showInterstitial();
                }
            }

            // Erro! não conseguiu carregar 
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {}

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                goToNextLevel();
            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Mostra o anúncio, se ele está pronto. 
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void goToNextLevel() {
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }
```

Comment: Não deu Certo, tá dando falha:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.smapps.testeinterstitialstack.MainActivity$1.onAdLoaded(MainActivity.java:35)

Comment: Veja se adicionou esta linha: **Long exibirAte = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+5000;**

Comment: ok adicionei, mas continua apresentando o erro